# How to test jest.fn().mock.calls in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing React Native component with Enzyme and Jest. I have been able to test whether mocked function is called (Alert.alert in this case), like this:

```
Alert.alert = jest.fn();
someButton.simulate('Press');

expect(Alert.alert.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

And that approach have worked nicely.

Anyhow, I have a Login button, which launches a fetch. My fetch function is like this:

```
fetch(ipAddress, {
           ...
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if (responseJson.login === 'success') {
                    Alert.alert('Login', 'Logged in succesfully!');
                    console.log('i'm here');
```

I have mocked a fetch with promises. I added console prints to my fetch function, and noticed that they are printed within test case, like I expected. That means *'i'm here'* is printed when test is run.

Anyhow, when I simulate login button press in test case, Alert.alert.mock.calls.length is zero. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you asking how to test a fetch call that returns a promise? Or are you asking why your test returns 0 and not 1?

Comment: @wuno I'm asking that why mocked function's call count does not update when it's called in asynchronous function

Comment: I would suspect the reason it is not 1 is cause it is not done yet. So it is still 0 since it has not returned anything at that point. It does not appear you are handling it as a promise. So when you look at this page in the section that explains handling promises, use your expect in the part of the code that handles the callback. So using .then https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: @wuno, if it's not done yet, how came console.log('i'm here') gets printed in test case?

Comment: I am not sure, but why not try using the suggested methods for handling promises to see if that can help figure it out? I have had plenty of problems testing promises myself. So I understand what your trying to wrap your head around. Also you will notice that promises dont return the expected data unless you handle them as a promise. If you put that in a variable and console log it, you will notice that the value it returns is not correct. It will be a long string representing a promise. Unless you use the method jest provides to resolve a promise.

Comment: @wuno, My interpretation of that console print thingy was totally wrong. It turned out that everything is printed, even though execution of test case is over. I think you are actually right. Maybe I just need to gain better understanding of promises and keep digging. Thank you for answers and support!

Comment: Yes, the guy who answered is correct and saying the same thing I was telling you. It is perfectly ok that this is confusing to you, it is confusing to all of us. Testing react is super hard and you have to decide where it ends. If you test a math function that returns a value, that is easy.  But when you test front end code it is hard to decide what a good test is. In your case promises make it harder. use the example the guy gave you in the answer below. if that does not solve you problem, tell me and I will make a working example with your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check this with react native, but I did write some tests for service invocations in React (I did use Flux which you didn't - but that's fine, it's the same principle in a different spot). Essentially, the promise chain is not yet done when you do the `expect`. This means, that both `Alert` and `console.log` are being performed *after* the `expect`, because the default promise implementation puts all next steps to the end of the event queue.

One way to overcome this is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-promises - the `beforeEach` method in your spec needs to call `install` along something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  Q=require('q');
  mp=require('mock-promises');
  mp.install(Q.makePromise);
  mp.reset();
  // more init code
});
```

and don't forget

```
afterEach(() => {
  mp.uninstall();
});
```

In case you don't use Q (which I did at that time), above link gives you instructions of how to install for other promises.

Now you have promises that don't put things to the end of the event queue and you can instead call the next `then` via calling `mp.tick()`. In your case, that would be something along of

```
it("...", () => {
  Alert.alert = jest.fn();
  someButton.simulate('Press');
  mp.tick();
  mp.tick(); // then and then
  expect(Alert.alert.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Another way, **out of the box in jest** is to append another `then` with the `expects` and *returning* the whole promise. You can find details here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html

Basically, this is what it would look like:

```
functionReturningPromise = () => {
  // do something
  return thePromise;
}

// now testing it
it("...", () => {
  return /* !!! */ functionReturningPromise().then(() => {
    expect(/*something*/).toBeSth();
  });
});
```

In your case, this is going to be hard, however, as you don't get a handle  of the promise in your test code. You could, however, split out all the fetch logic into a dedicated method (which returns the promise at least for testing) and write a test for that.

Comment: Thanks for answer Sebastian! You were totally right. Simple things are the most beautiful. I just moved the response handling logic to separate function. That worked out nicely!

Comment: To be more precise, testing that logic worked nicely =)